# Audio Keeps Playing After Closing Window With WebBrowser In WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, caliburn.micro

I have a window that is being displayed by Caliburn.Micro.  This window contains a WebBrowser control that can play a youtube video.  If the Youtube video is playing and the user closes the window, the audio continues to play in the background.  How do I get the audio to stop playing when the window closes?  I'm assuming the view isn't being disposed for some reason.

**Display The Window**

```
public void Handle(VideoButtonClick message)
{
    var manager = new WindowManager();
    Video = new VideoViewModel(message.VideoID);
    dynamic settings = new ExpandoObject();
    settings.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
    settings.Icon = null;

    manager.ShowDialog(Video, null, settings);
}
```

**View Displayed Within Window**

```
<UserControl .....>
    <Grid>
        <WebBrowser ctrl:BrowserBehavior.Html="{Binding VideoHTML}"
                    ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
                    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Set up a dispose method and make sure all event handlers are disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `IDeactivate` in your `VideoViewModel`:

```
public class VideoViewModel : PropertyChangedBase, IDeactivate
{
    private bool _isClosing;
    public bool IsClosing
    {
        get { return _isClosing; }
        set
        {
            _isClosing = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => IsClosing);
        }
    }

    public void Deactivate(bool close)
    {
        IsClosing = close;
    }

    public event EventHandler<DeactivationEventArgs> AttemptingDeactivation;
    public event EventHandler<DeactivationEventArgs> Deactivated;
}
```

In the `Deactivate` method set a property called `IsClosing`.

In your view:

```
<UserControl .....
             x:Name="ThisUserControl">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsClosing}" Value="True">
            <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="DisposeBrowser" TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=ThisUserControl}"/>
        </ei:DataTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

    <Grid>
        <WebBrowser x:Name="MyWebBrowser"
                    ctrl:BrowserBehavior.Html="{Binding VideoHTML}"
                    ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
                    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And in the code-behind of your `UserControl`:

```
public void DisposeBrowser()
{
    MyWebBrowser.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: I have regular windows form app: My Exit event is just = `webBrowser1.Dispose()` on my webBrowser control followed by `this.Close();` on form. (Close() form was not enough.) This seems to do the trick - disposing control before calling form close. voted ^